# DES encryption error in Java (Illegal base64 character 20)

Tags: java, encryption, des

I am trying to make a little encryption/decryption software for my APCS-A final project. I have most of it done with various text ciphers and such, but I am trying to get DES encryption to work as like the big thing. I couldn't get it working in the main program so I created its own little thing to try to learn and test it first. I think I've gotten decently far, but I am getting stuck on an error that I can't figure out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.util.Base64;
public class BigETest
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException,IllegalBlockSizeException,BadPaddingException
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter text: ");
        String t = kbd.nextLine();
        String[] rets = en(t);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: "+ rets[0]);
        System.out.println("Key: " + rets[1]);
        String dec = de(rets[0],rets[1]);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: "+dec);
    }
    public static String[] en(String inText) throws BadPaddingException,IllegalBlockSizeException,InvalidKeyException,NoSuchPaddingException,NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] text = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(inText);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(text);
        String encrypted = new String(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes));
        
        byte[] rawKey = key.getEncoded();
        String stringKey = new String(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(rawKey));
        
        String[] ret = {encrypted,stringKey};
        return ret;
    }
    public static String de(String inText, String inKey) throws BadPaddingException,IllegalBlockSizeException,InvalidKeyException,NoSuchPaddingException,NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        byte[] keyB = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(inKey);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyB, "DES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] text = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(inText);
        byte[] fin = cipher.doFinal(text);
        String dec = new String(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(fin));
        return dec;
    }
}
```

The code works sometimes if the input is short and doesn't have spaces in it

```
Enter text: test
Encrypted: BOM9tFOUfWc=
Key: bq2ooSbc1n8=
Decrypted: test
```

but falls apart if the input is a bit longer

```
Enter text: BigTest
Encrypted: jme0nIAHXyA=
Key: 90UxVwetj2g=
Decrypted: BigTess=
```

And then gives me an error if there are any spaces

```
Enter text: bigger test

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:538)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:561)
    at BigETest.en(BigETest.java:34)
    at BigETest.main(BigETest.java:20)
```

I have tried changing things up and looked around both on here and just around anyplace I could find on Google for some answers, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your encryption function `en(String inText)`you have `Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(inText);`. Why do you decode the input in your encryption function. Sure that will fail as soon as you have a blank in the input. There is nothing to decode on the input text.

Comment: Why are you calling Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(inText)? What is wrong with simply using inText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)?

Comment: @ewramner changing that line doesn't work, it gives this output:
Enter text: test
Encrypted: 1OGMmmZO5fw=
Key: znVD1TcqTJI=
Decrypted: dGVzdA==

Comment: Not so strange as you use encodeToString when you decrypt. You need to be consistent.